# C++: Allocate memory in function

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to allocate memory for the object in a function. However, it doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
class MyClass { ... };
void foo(MyClass *mc) { mc = new MyClass; }

int main() {
    MyClass *mc;
    foo(mc);
    if (mc == NULL)
        std::cout << "Faile" << std::endl;
}
```

I am no good at pointer things. Can anyone give me an explanation about my mistake? Thanks!

Comment: _"I am no good at pointer things."_ Why are you using them then? For [most cases in c++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) you're neither supposed to use, nor need raw pointers, and manage the memory yourself.

Comment: He might be learning C++. I suggest you (wking) to read some C++ books, since pointers are important for, however you have to avoid pointer usage as much as possible. Pointer of MyClass must be initialized, you can not use a pointer without initializing it. This code part should be compiled at all. On the other hand, you might use 'MyClass mc' which would create an instance for you. Prefer references instead of pointers in your functions, too.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but I am still learnning it. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really wanted your thing to work, you would code using a reference to a pointer:

```
void foo(MyClass *&mc) { mc = new MyClass; }
```

but that is ridiculous. Just return the pointer:

```
MyClass* foo () { return new MyClass; }
```

Actually, you rarely need to do such things. Use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory).

You definitely need to read a lot more about C++ (e.g. Stroustrup's [Programming : Principles & Practice using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) & [C++ Programming Language (4<sup>th</sup> edition)](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) etc...), and you should use a modern [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) implementation (e.g. version 4.9 or better of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Read about [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error), [Rule of Three / Rule of Five](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) ...